# После удаления tcmd слетели ассоциации с .bat файлами (Windows 10)

Tags: cmd, windows-10, bat

Я удалил прогу "tcmd" и .bat файлы внезапно перестали работать, появилось окно выбора (скрин приложен), где есть только tcmd, пытался через вкладку "Ещё приложения" выбрать cmd.exe, но выдаёт ошибку "Не удаётся сопоставить тип файла с этой программы" (скрин приложен), пробовал прогу "rstassociations", не помогла. Удалил я корректно, через параметры. Есть какие-нибудь способы починить без сброса винды?

[image: Окно выбора]
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: https://superuser.com/q/53948/910710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В результате тогда антивирус просто это исправил, посчитав последствием трояна, который я схватил после появления этой проблемы. Как он это сделал - не знаю

P.s. Ответ очень поздно, так-как я просто забыл о вопросе

Answer (score 1):

Проверте этот раздел реестра

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"
```

После исправлений сделать логоф/логон.

Если не поможет, то нужно проверить, есть ли проблема у других пользователей в системе. Лучше создать нового пользователя, зайти и проверить. Если там всё ок, то таким образом можно пересоздать свой профиль (это гораздо менее затратно, чем переустановка всей ОС)

Comment: Спасибо большое, но мне не помогло, отличалось только [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command] @="\"%1\" %*", я исправил но ничего не изменилось

Comment: А логоф/логон сделали после исправления?

Comment: Если не поможет, то нужно проверить, есть ли проблема у других пользователей в системе. Лучше создать нового пользователя, зайти и проверить. Если там всё ок, то таким образом можно пересоздать свой профиль (это гораздо менее затратно, чем переустановка всей ОС)

Comment: Я перезапускал ПК после изменения, пользователь только один. Попробую создать ещё одного пользователя. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Если поможет, то не забудьте пометить ответ как полезный (стрелка вверх) и как решивший проблему (птичка)

Comment: Не помогло, с другого пользователя другая ошибка, но я не знаю как добавить скриншот к этому комментарию. Получается только сброс винды?